# Understanding the need for generating overviews in Sentinel-1 image processing via GDAL

Tags: gdal, sentinel-snap, image-pyramids

I am currently working with the European Space Agency SNAP Engine for processing Sentinel-1 imagery. I am investigating a workflow implemented by a former employee. After exporting the files as TIFFs, a series of GDAL commands are executed. I've noticed that the process involves generating overviews or "pyramids," but I am unsure about their necessity and potential for optimization.

My main objective is to optimize the workflow and reduce file storage requirements by approximately 25%. However, I am uncertain about the significance of generating these lower-quality overviews, specifically in the context of the following usage scenarios:

1. The images are primarily utilized for image statistics calculations in Python.
2. In some cases, the images are used in a Convolutional Neural Network.

Considering that the Sentinel-1 images are not intended for visualization purposes in tools like QGIS and are solely accessed via Python scripts, where the pixel values are processed individually, I question the need for generating overviews. What are the implications and potential benefits of excluding the generation of overviews in this context?

The commands I have found in our pipeline are as follows:

```
run_command(f"gdaladdo -r average {tiffile} 2 4 8 16 32")
```

The above command creates five lower-quality overviews of the original image

```
run_command(f"gdal_translate {tiffile} {output_file} "" -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW"
```

The final command makes sure the variants are saved with the `-co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES`

By comprehending the implications of not generating these overviews, I hope to optimise the processing workflow and reduce storage requirements while still maintaining the necessary data quality for statistical analysis and CNN training. Can you provide insights or recommendations regarding this matter?

Comment: Image pyramids are used for rendering, not statistics. If you don't think it necessary, try it first in some area, measure the performance impact. There are likely benefits and costs to your plan, but without full details we could only guess on the best procedure.

Comment: You can save roughly 25% of disk space by dropping the overviews. Or actually more, because you seem to generate a LZW compressed image but the overviews are not compressed. Overviews are useless for you if you need to access the full resolution pixels in any case. I recommend to create external overviews for testing by running gdaladdo with the `-ro` option. When you are sure that you do not need overviews you can simple delete the *.ovr files.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I will devise a test where I generate conditioned images with and without overviews, then push it through the statistics pipelines and see if the output statistics are identical. 
I will come back to provide the results - How do I distribute points here when you are both very helpful